# how to fix seekbar-bar-thumb-centering-issues

Tags: android, seekbar

I have set thumb image of a seek bar but my thumb looks little below of seek bar. How to set thumb at proper position of a seekbar. Have a look on the attached image[image]

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/PP_Player_SeekBar" 
         android:thumb="@drawable/music_player_playerhead"
         android:paddingLeft="8dip"
         android:paddingRight="8dip"                 
         android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_drawable_xml_background"
         android:layout_width="236dip"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="47dip"></SeekBar>
```

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Saoo

Comment: I think the issue is with the image itself "music_player_playerhead". So do check the thumb file if the circle in the middle.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Set minHeight and maxHeight same as the height of seekbar. eg

```
<SeekBar 
    android:id="@+id/PP_Player_SeekBar"  
    android:thumb="@drawable/music_player_playerhead"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"   
    android:paddingRight="8dip"                 
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_drawable_xml_background"
    android:layout_width="236dip" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="47dip"
    android:minHeight="11dip"
    android:maxHeight="11dip" />
```

See the following url
http://qtcstation.com/2011/05/android-how-to-fix-seekbar-bar-thumb-centering-issues/

Comment: what if, I am using layout weight, as in that case, height would be 0dp :)

Comment: What explains why this should work? This does nothing for me. My alignment is actually fine on API 21 and up I only have this issue on older API's. My guess is the thumb is aligned correctly but it is the background that isn't.

Answer (score 23):

In fact, it is enough to define `maxHeight` to a big number like 1000dp.

This also has the benefit of working with `height=wrap_content` and `height=match_parent`.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Define a basic SeekBar in XML layout with maxHeight 1000dp. Then I can set everything programmatically and the thumb appears in the dead center and everything else is good. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! That's what I need!!

Comment: Quick and to the point. This should be the selected answer!
This also has the benefit of working with height=wrap_content and height=match_parent

Comment: that solve the problem for me i set maxHeight to 1000dp

Answer (score 5):

For me, the issue is more related to the vertical centering of the background (track drawable).  This is the flawed drawable code I used originally (which generated the problem), as suggested by Android developer and other StackOverflow entries:

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_track"/>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <scale
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress2"
        android:scaleWidth="100%" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <scale
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:scaleWidth="100%" />
</item>
```

The problem here is the first item, which relates to the background of the SeekBar.  Many entries will tell you to set the layout_minHeight feature to some large value to avoid a vertical spatial disconnect between the thumb and its track.  This was not the solution for me - when viewed on a tablet, the background was still drawing to its smaller phone-based size - so the track was consistently positioned well above the center of the SeekBar track.  The solution is to remove this entry in the SeekBar drawable, so it now looks like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress2"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Then, in the style definition of the SeekBar, set the layout_background to the the track drawable.  Mine looks like this:

```
<style name="styleSeekBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/base_0dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/seekbar_track</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/abratingbar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/base_29dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/base_29dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/base_10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/base_10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/base_10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/base_10dp</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
</style>
```

(Previously, the background setting here was just a color [white].).

This is the entry in my layout, which uses both the style and the drawables:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar_page_number"
    style="@style/styleSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/base_29dp"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/base_29dp"
    android:maxHeight="@dimen/base_29dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/base_230dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:progress="1"
    android:max="20"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/abseekbar"
    android:thumb="@drawable/abseekbar_thumb"/>
```

So, to summarize, do not set the background (track) feature in your custom SeekBar drawable, set it in the layout_background feature of your custom SeekBar style.  This ensures the track is always vertically centered in a horizontal SeekBar.

Comment: Good answer! First try to understand if its the Thumb or the Progress that are not centered. This solution is for when the Progress is not centered inside your seekbar

Answer (score 2):

I simply resolved the misaligned horizontal seekbar thumb by setting `layout_height` of the seekbar to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`