# Android: Drawable vertically alignment for SeekBar

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

This is waht I need to achieve with `xml` `drawable` for `SeekBar`:
[image]

I tried many different variations and this is best I could make.

This is `seekbar_thumb_drawable.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="@color/accent_color"/>

    <size
        android:height="20dp"
        android:width="20dp" />

</shape>
```

This is `seekbar_drawable.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:height="5dp"
        android:top="7.5dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/seekbar_background" />
            <corners android:radius="2.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:height="10dp"
        android:top="5dp">
        <clip>
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/seekbar_progress" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**Result on API 18:**
Problem is that lines are not verticaly centered.

[image]

**Result on API 24:**
This display exactly how I want it to display.

[image]

Is there any possible solution to make this appear as on first picture on all devices from `API 16`?
I do not want to use nine-patch, because I need to use color from resources.
I tried `padding`, `gravity`, `top`, `bottom`, `inter-shape`, `line`, `rectangle` but I could not find solution...

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `android:height` and `android:width` for `<item>` are only available for API 23 and above. If you use these attributes for API below 23, it will not give you an error, but simply ignore it.

In your case, `android:height="5dp"`, and `android:height="10dp"` are not being applied.

If you look at the relevant [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerInsetRight(int,%20int)) or , it says that these were added in API level 23.

Answer (score 1):

Make update in your drawable files.

In seekbar_thumb_drawable.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <solid android:color="@color/accent_color" />

            <size
                android:width="20dp"
                android:height="20dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

seekbar_drawable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:height="5dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/seekbar_background" />
            <corners android:radius="2.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:height="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/seekbar_progress" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I m using gravity in item, So that drawable item draw in center.

Answer (score 0):

You probably faced with already known issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7404421/3225458) is the solution for it. You should define `maxHeight` and `minHeight` of the `SeekBar` the same as the height of it. Or you can even set `maxHeight` to some big value like `1000dp`, if you exepect your height to be `wrap_content`, like mentioned below the suggested answer in the same thread.

```
<SeekBar 
    android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_drawable"         
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_drawable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="1000dp"
    <!-- OR -->
    android:maxHeight="16dp"
    android:minHeight="16dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue in **Low API** of ***thumb drawable*** come above the line So what I did for it.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar_transparency"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/seekbar_thumb_size_space"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/seekbar_thumb_size_space"
    android:progress="100"
    android:theme="@style/SeekbarTheme"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_drawable" />
```

style.xml

```
<!--Seekbar background change-->
<style name="SeekbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- active seekbar progress track color -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorSeekBar</item>
    <!-- inactive seekbar progress track color  -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorGray</item>
</style>
```

thumb_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="2.5dp"
        android:left="2.5dp"
        android:right="2.5dp"
        android:top="2.5dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
         android:width="@dimen/seekbar_thumb_size"
         android:height="@dimen/seekbar_thumb_size" />
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        <solid android:color="#201DE9B6" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/seekbar_thumb_size"
                android:height="@dimen/seekbar_thumb_size" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="#AA1DE9B6" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

dimes.xml

```
<!--Seeckbar thumb size-->
<dimen name="seekbar_thumb_size">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="seekbar_thumb_size_space">5dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="3dp"
    android:minHeight="3dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/nnl_bg_seek_bar_progress"
    android:splitTrack="false"
    android:thumb="@drawable/nnl_sel_seek_bar_thumb"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
    />
```

The code above is my way. You may need to pay attention to these attributes: maxHeight / minHeight / splitTrack.